# ActiveRecord 'where' clause using function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to apply filters on an ActiveRecord::Relation. I would like to apply a 'where' clause (or the equivalent) to make the following call.

```
record = Record.all
record.where(record.remaing_units > 5)
```

I know this would be easy to get coding a fonction and passing it 2 arguments but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do it, more 'where' like.

EDIT : remaining_units is a method of Record class calculating subtraction between 2 fields.

Comment: `remaing_units` is a field on `Record` model ?

Comment: Urg sorry, I wrote it in title but not in the description... It's a function, calculating the subtraction between 2 fields.

Comment: You can do `Record.all.map{|record| record.remaining_units > 5 }` but in this case you'll get an array, not AR relation

Comment: what DB engine you are using ?

Comment: @Aeradriel use `send` method something like this `record.where(record.send("record.remaining_units> ", "5"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :remaining_space, ->(n) {
    where("records.field_1 - records.field_2 > ?", n)
  }
end

Record.remaining_space(5)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that you can make arithmetic operation in with SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use methods as mysql query.

You can run the same function as sql method:

```
Record.where('a + b > 5')
```

Or get all records from the db and use ruby `select` method:

```
Record.all.select{ |r| r. remaing_units > 5 }
```

** you can try [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem for better query